# nestjsx/crud - how to change errors responses

Tags: nestjs, crud, typeorm

I need to change the error response 404 error for exemple.
This is de case:

```
@Entity('role')
export class RoleEntity extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 100, nullable: false })
  name: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class RoleService extends TypeOrmCrudService<RoleEntity> {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(RoleEntity) repo) {
    super(repo);
  }
}

@Crud({
  model: {
    type: RoleEntity,
  },
})
@Controller('role')
export class RoleController implements CrudController<RoleEntity> {
  constructor(public service: RoleService) {}
}
```

When i try to get an id not created in the base i got the error

```
{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "message": "RoleEntitynot found",
  "error": "Not Found"
}
```

I want to change this error to something like this:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "message": "The given id was not found in the database",
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: It's difficult to understand where's your service and where's your controller. consider editing the question with proper formatting. Also try to add the service and controller methods as well.

Comment: This methods are generetad by lib https://github.com/nestjsx/crud, with the decorator @Crud.

Comment: I mean separating your services and controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Override nestjs/crud `getOneBase` method ([Doc nestjs/crud](https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/wiki/Controllers#routes-override))

```
@Override('getOneBase')
getOneAndDoStuff(
    @ParsedRequest() req: CrudRequest,
    ) {
    // Catch below error and return your message
    this.base.getOneBase(req)

    return ...;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the base call in try catch statement like below, by this you can override errors object.

```
@Override()
async getOne(@ParsedRequest() req: CrudRequest) {
 try {
  return await this.base.getOneBase(req);
 } catch (error) {
  throw new HttpException(
    {
      returnCode: error.response.statusCode,
      message: error.response.message,
      type: ResponseTypes[error.response.statusCode],
    },
    error.status
  );
 }
}
```